# how to put second field name in codeigniter 3 form validation's greater_than rule

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have 2 fields and I want to compare their value with the rule `min_val` must be less or equal to `max_val` and I also need to put the second field's name (max_val) in the error message.

below is my code so far:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
  'field'=>'min_val',
  'label'=>'minimum value',
  'rules'=>'callback__check_less_than_equal_to[max_val]'
));

function _check_less_than_equal_to($field1, $field2)
{
  if ($field1 <= $field2)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    $str = 'The %s field must be less than or equal to %s field';
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_less_than_equal_to', $str);
    return false;
  }
}
```

the problem is that when I input 13 in the `min_val` and 5 in the `max_val`, it doesn't trigger an error message. and I've just found out that the `$field2` contains a string value `max_val` instead of the integer value `5`. how should I fix this code? I don't understand the sequence of parameters in the custom validation method and there doesn't seem to be any explanation in the CI docs..

Comment: Can you not define them as integer values? `function _check_less_than_equal_to(int $field1, int $field2)` or does the validator not allow it? [Check this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0fbd32d28a362eb78d736fa9ff3c3ce5837c9ec4).

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal no. the `$field2` contains the literal string 'max_val' so when I try to define the parameters as int, it gives a TypeError Argument 2 passed to _check_less_than_equal_to() must be of the type int, string given